# Power calculation for single phase heat treat oven

Tags: power, three-phase

We have an old heat treat oven that was intended to run off of 240V single phase (US).  In actuality it is running off of two legs of a 3 phase 480V->208V (delta to wye) transformer.  The transformer is dedicated to this oven alone and the third leg of the secondary is unused.  My question is, do I still use the sqrt of 3 when calculating power?  It draws 80A according to my clamp meter, so is it 208x80 = 16.640KW or 208x80x1.73 = 28.787KW?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with three-phase power calculations, you use the square root of \$3\$ (approximately \$1.73\$) as a conversion factor. The correct formula for calculating power in a three-phase system is:

$$\text{P}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\text{V}_\text{line}\cdot\text{I}_\text{line}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi\right)\tag1$$

Where:

- \$\text{P}\$ is the power in watts;
- \$\text{V}_\text{line}\$ is the line-to-line voltage in volts;
- \$\text{I}_\text{line}\$ is the line current in amperes;
- \$\cos\left(\varphi\right)\$ is the power factor.

In your case, since you're working with a single-phase load on a three-phase system, the line-to-line voltage \$\text{V}_\text{line}\$ would be the actual voltage, which is \$208\$ V. The line current \$\text{I}_\text{line}\$ is \$80\$ A.

So, the power \$\text{P}\$ would be:

$$\text{P}=\sqrt{3}\cdot208\cdot80\cdot\cos\left(\varphi\right)\tag2$$

However, in many cases, single-phase loads in a three-phase system have a power factor close to 1 (unity). If the power factor is indeed close to \$1\$, then you can simplify the formula to:

$$\text{P}=\sqrt{3}\cdot208\cdot80\cdot1=16640\sqrt{3}\approx28821.33\space\text{W}\tag3$$

So, to answer your question, you would use the first formula if you know the power factor, and the second formula if the power factor is close to \$1\$. If you don't have information about the power factor, you can use the second formula as a reasonable approximation.

Comment: Why are you using √3 when this is explicitly about a *single-phase* load?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more why √3 is needed with a single phase load?  Is it because there is never a zero crossing at the same time with the two voltage wave forms being 120 degrees apart?  Since this is heating elements I'm going to assume power factor is very close to 1.

Comment: Imagine a single phase resistive load where you measure 80 A and 208 VAC and the supply is a black box. This looks like 16.64 kW to me.

Answer (score 0):

After brushing up on vector math to prove it to myself, the answer would seem to be P = 208V x 80A = 16,640W.  Each of the 2 legs in use of the WYE secondary would have 120V x 80A = 9600W.

X component for leg 1 is: $$9600\times\cos{(0)} = 9600W$$
Y component for leg 1 is: $$9600\times\sin{(0)} = j0W$$

X component for leg 2 is: $$9600\times\cos{(120)} = -4800W$$
Y component for leg 2 is: $$9600\times\sin{(120)} = j8313.84W$$

Total power to the load (heating coils) would be $$P = \sqrt{(9600- (-4800))^2 + (0^2 - 8313.84^2)} = 16,628.68W$$

Same as simply doing $$208V\times80A=16,640W$$ (some voltage rounding error included)